# Few probems in XML Schema validation

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I'm trying to validate my Schema project built to match my XML file, but I'm getting a few errors:

cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'o:browar'. No child element is expected at this point. [24]

cvc-id.2: There are multiple occurrences of ID value 'p100'. [38] (and any other id from p100 to p105 have this error)

cvc-attribute.3: The value 'p100' of attribute 'idref' on element 'o:kraj' is not valid with respect to its type, 'null'. [38]

cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'o:lista_producentów'. One of '{"http://piwowarzy.pl/alko":piwo, "http://piwowarzy.pl/alko":browar}' is expected. [352]

cvc-attribute.3: The value 'p100' of attribute 'id' on element 'o:producent' is not valid with respect to its type, 'null'. [353] (and any other id from p100 to p105 have this error)

Here are code samples:

piwowarzy.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet typek="text/css" href="astyle.css" ?>

<p:projekt xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://piwowarzy.pl/projekt main.xsd"
           xmlns:p="http://piwowarzy.pl/projekt"
           xmlns:o="http://piwowarzy.pl/alko"
           xmlns:c="http://piwowarzy.pl/info"
           xmlns:cmn="http://piwowarzy.pl/tytul">

    <p:tytul> Piwa europejskie </p:tytul>
    <c:info>
            <c:autorzy>Bartłomiej Mikołajczyk, Marcin Mucha</c:autorzy>
            <c:opis2>Arkusz ten zawiera dane o różnych rodzajach piw, informacje o nich oraz krótkie opisy.</c:opis2>
            <c:data>Ostatnia data modyfikacji: 25.10.2018</c:data>
    </c:info>
    <p:piwa_i_alkohole>
        <o:piwo id="p01" from="polskie">
            <o:nazwa>Żywiec</o:nazwa>
            <o:chmiel>
                <o:kraj idref="p100">Polska</o:kraj>
                <o:region>Lubelszczyzna</o:region>
            </o:chmiel>
            <o:browar typek="jasne">
                <o:name>Żywiec</o:name>
                <o:rozlewnia>Żywiec</o:rozlewnia>
                <o:rok_założenia>1856</o:rok_założenia>     

                <o:alkohol>5,6%</o:alkohol>
            </o:browar>
            <o:opis>Piwo Żywiec od momentu powstania w 1856 r. jest warzone stale i niezmiennie w tym samym miejscu – browarze w Żywcu. 
            Najsłynniejsze polskie piwo typu pilzneńskiego. Absolutna klasyka gatunku i idealne połączenie tradycji z nowoczesnością.</o:opis>
        </o:piwo>

        <o:piwo id="p02" from="polskie">
            <o:nazwa>Namysłów Pils</o:nazwa>
            <o:chmiel>
                <o:kraj idref="p100">Polska</o:kraj>
                <o:region>Opolszczyzna</o:region>
            </o:chmiel>
            <o:browar typek="jasne">
                <o:name>Namysłów</o:name>
                <o:rozlewnia>Namysłów</o:rozlewnia>
                <o:rok_założenia>1321</o:rok_założenia>     

                <o:alkohol>6,0%</o:alkohol>
            </o:browar>
            <o:opis>Namysłów Pils to piwo jasne pełne. Piwo to powstaje w oparciu o tradycyjne metody produkcji takie jak otwarte kadzie fermentacyjne, które browar utrzymuje i pielęgnuje aby było ono wyjątkowe w swoim smaku. 
            Również opakowanie Pilsa nawiązuje do tradycji browaru Namysłów, jego regionalnego charakteru oraz autentyczności pochodzenia.</o:opis>
        </o:piwo>

        <o:piwo id="p03" from="polskie">
            <o:nazwa>Harnaś Jasne Pełne</o:nazwa>
            <o:chmiel>
                <o:kraj idref="p100">Polska</o:kraj>
                <o:region>Małopolska</o:region>
            </o:chmiel>
            <o:browar typek="jasne">
                <o:name>Okocim</o:name>
                <o:rozlewnia>Okocim</o:rozlewnia>
                <o:rok_założenia>1845</o:rok_założenia>

                <o:alkohol>6,0%</o:alkohol>
            </o:browar>
            <o:opis>Szlachetne męskie piwo pełne siły, humoru i pogody ducha. Orzeźwia i cieszy swoim wyjątkowym smakiem i aromatem. Idealne do pracy.</o:opis>
        </o:piwo>

        <o:piwo id="p04" from="polskie">
            <o:nazwa>Lech Premium</o:nazwa>
            <o:chmiel>
                <o:kraj idref="p100">Polska</o:kraj>
                <o:region>Wielkopolska</o:region>
            </o:chmiel>
            <o:browar typek="ciemne">
                <o:name>Lech Browary Wielkopolski</o:name>
                <o:rozlewnia>Poznań</o:rozlewnia>
                <o:rok_założenia>1975</o:rok_założenia>

                <o:alkohol>5,2%</o:alkohol>
            </o:browar>
            <o:opis>Lech Premium to jedna z czołowych marek Kompanii Piwowarskiej, która istnieje na rynku już od początku lat osiemdziesiątych. Doprowadzony do perfekcji proces produkcji Lecha w poznańskim browarze, jednym z najnowocześniejszych browarów w Europie, jest gwarancją najwyższej jakości piwa Lech. 
            Piwo Lech Premium to harmonia smaku i odpowiedniego nagazowania, które nadają mu doskonałych właściwości orzeźwiających, idealne połączenie mocy ze szlachetną goryczą dojrzałego chmielu. Piwo warzone z naturalnych składników.</o:opis>
        </o:piwo>

        <o:piwo id="p05" from="polskie">
            <o:nazwa>Perła Export</o:nazwa>
            <o:chmiel>
                <o:kraj idref="p100">Polska</o:kraj>
                <o:region>Lubelszczyzna</o:region>
            </o:chmiel>
            <o:browar typek="pełne">
                <o:name>Perła – Browary Lubelskie</o:name>
                <o:rozlewnia>Lublin</o:rozlewnia>
                <o:rok_założenia>1946</o:rok_założenia>

                <o:alkohol>5,6%</o:alkohol>
            </o:browar>
            <o:opis>Perła Export to kwintesencja smaku, zapachu i koloru Wyżyny Lubelskiej uznana przez smakoszy na całym świecie.</o:opis>
        </o:piwo>

        <o:piwo id="p06" from="polskie">
            <o:nazwa>Żubr</o:nazwa>
            <o:chmiel>
                <o:kraj idref="p100">Polska</o:kraj>
                <o:region>Wielkopolska</o:region>
            </o:chmiel>
            <o:browar typek="pełne">
                <o:name>Browar Dojlidy</o:name>
                <o:rozlewnia>Białystok</o:rozlewnia>
                <o:rok_założenia>1768</o:rok_założenia>

                <o:alkohol>6,0%</o:alkohol>
            </o:browar>
            <o:opis>Żubr kojarzony jest z nieskażoną przyrodą, której bliskość wpływa na jego niepowtarzalny smak. Warzony z naturalnych składników od ponad 200 lat na so:kraju Puszczy Białowieskiej, jest idealny na zakończenie każdego dnia. 
            Żubr jest pełen spokoju i harmonii, znakomity w czasie relaksu na świeżym powietrzu po trudach tygodnia. To druga pod względem wielkości sprzedaży marka piwa w Polsce.</o:opis>
        </o:piwo>

        <o:piwo id="p07" from="polskie">
            <o:nazwa>Tyskie</o:nazwa>
            <o:chmiel>
                <o:kraj idref="p100">Polska</o:kraj>
                <o:region>Śląsk</o:region>
            </o:chmiel>
            <o:browar typek="ciemne">
                <o:name>Tyskie Browary Książęce</o:name>
                <o:rozlewnia>Tychy</o:rozlewnia>
                <o:rok_założenia>1613</o:rok_założenia>

                <o:alkohol>5,6%</o:alkohol>
            </o:browar>
            <o:opis>Tyskie jest niekwestionowanym liderem polskiego rynku piwa.Od lat zdobywa uznanie zarówno w kraju jak i zagranicą. Wielokrotnie zostało uhonorowane najbardziej prestiżowymi laurami branży piwowarskiej. 
            Koneserzy piwa cenią w Tyskim łagodny chmielowy zapach, złocisty kolor oraz gęstą białą pianę.</o:opis>
        </o:piwo>

        <o:piwo id="p08" from="polskie">
            <o:nazwa>Tatra Jasne Pełne</o:nazwa>
            <o:chmiel>
                <o:kraj idref="p100">Polska</o:kraj>
                <o:region>Mazury</o:region>
            </o:chmiel>
            <o:browar typek="ciemne">
                <o:name>Elbląg</o:name>
                <o:rozlewnia>Elbląg</o:rozlewnia>
                <o:rok_założenia>1872</o:rok_założenia>

                <o:alkohol>6,0%</o:alkohol>
            </o:browar>
            <o:opis>Tatra to marka znana i ceniona przez piwoszy w Polsce, a jej popularność stale rośnie. Warzone jest w renomowanych browarach Grupy Żywiec. Tatra Jasne Pełne to klasyczne piwo typu pilzneńskiego o wyraźnym aromacie i doskonałym, orzeźwiającym smaku.</o:opis>
        </o:piwo>

        <o:piwo id="p09" from="polskie">
            <o:nazwa>Redd’s Red</o:nazwa>
            <o:chmiel>
                <o:kraj idref="p100">Polska</o:kraj>
                <o:region>Wielkopolska</o:region>
            </o:chmiel>
            <o:browar typek="jasne">
                <o:name>Kompania Piwowarska</o:name>
                <o:rozlewnia>Poznań</o:rozlewnia>
                <o:rok_założenia>1996</o:rok_założenia>

                <o:alkohol>4,5%</o:alkohol>
            </o:browar>
            <o:opis>Redd's Red to kombinacja charakterystycznej piwnej goryczki z kuszącym smakiem malin. Jest to połączenie tradycyjnego piwa z sokiem malinowym - i doskonała alternatywa dla osób lubiących piwo z sokiem. 
            Redd's Red to piwo o klarownym, delikatnie czerwonym zabarwieniu i malinowym zapachu.</o:opis>
        </o:piwo>

        <o:piwo id="p10" from="zagraniczne">
            <o:nazwa>Pilsner Urquell</o:nazwa>
            <o:chmiel>
                <o:kraj idref="p101">Czechy</o:kraj>
                <o:region>o:kraj pilzneński</o:region>
            </o:chmiel>
            <o:browar typek="pełne">
                <o:name>Plzeňský Prazdroj</o:name>
                <o:rozlewnia>Pilzno</o:rozlewnia>
                <o:rok_założenia>1842</o:rok_założenia>

                <o:alkohol>4,4%</o:alkohol>
            </o:browar>
            <o:opis>Pilsner Urquell to piwo, które zmieniło bieg historii piwa na świecie i ponad 160 lat temu dało początek całej kategorii pilznerów. Jego szlachetna złocista barwa, wyjątkowy smak i najwyższa jakość gwarantowane są przez doskonałą i niezmienną od 1842 roku recepturę. 
            Świat Pilsner Urquell to świat dojrzałości, wyrafinowanego smaku oraz wyjątkowego stylu.</o:opis>
        </o:piwo>

        <o:piwo id="p11" from="polskie">
            <o:nazwa>Ciechan Wyborne</o:nazwa>
            <o:chmiel>
                <o:kraj idref="p100">Polska</o:kraj>
                <o:region>Mazowieckie</o:region>
            </o:chmiel>
            <o:browar typek="pełne">
                <o:name>Ciechan</o:name>
                <o:rozlewnia>Ciechanów</o:rozlewnia>
                <o:rok_założenia>1864</o:rok_założenia>

                <o:alkohol>6,0%</o:alkohol>
            </o:browar>
            <o:opis>Piwo Ciechan Wyborne Niepasteryzowane produkowane przez Browar Ciechan jest warzone metodą dekokcyjną przy zachowaniu starych receptur. Urządzenia, jak i pomieszczenia technologiczne są historyczne, co ułatwiło odtworzenie procesu leżakowania i fermentacji. Tradycyjne procesy warzenia gwarantują niepowtarzalny aromat, klarowność i smak. 
            Piwo Ciechan Wyborne Niepasteryzowane jest filtrowane, posiada wyjątkowe walory smakowe, odżywcze i zdrowotne. Dzięki niskiej zawartości sodu może być spożywane przez osoby stosujące dietę bezsolną. W Warszawie i Mazowszu znane jako Wyborne Królewskie.</o:opis>
        </o:piwo>

        <o:piwo id="p12" from="zagraniczne">
            <o:nazwa>Heineken</o:nazwa>
            <o:chmiel>
                <o:kraj idref="p102">Holandia</o:kraj>
                <o:region>Holandia Południowa</o:region>
            </o:chmiel>
            <o:browar typek="jasne">
                <o:name>Heineken</o:name>
                <o:rozlewnia>Zoeterwoude</o:rozlewnia>
                <o:rok_założenia>1864</o:rok_założenia>

                <o:alkohol>5,0%</o:alkohol>
            </o:browar>
            <o:opis>Heineken, w charakterystycznej zielonej butelce, jest jedną z najsilniejszych międzynarodowych marek piwa. Jest sprzedawany na każdym kontynencie w ponad 180 krajach świata. W Polsce Heineken jest największą marką w segmencie International Premium, cenioną przez osoby szukające piwa najwyższej jakości. 
            Na polskim rynku Heineken pojawił się oficjalnie w 1994. Od stycznia 2000 stał się częścią oferty handlowej Grupy Żywiec. Od czerwca 2001 wedle tradycyjnej receptury, przy zachowaniu najwyższych standardów browarniczych, Heineken warzony jest w browarze w Żywcu.</o:opis>
        </o:piwo>

        <o:piwo id="p13" from="polskie">
            <o:nazwa>Kasztelan Niepasteryzowane</o:nazwa>
            <o:chmiel>
                <o:kraj idref="p100">Polska</o:kraj>
                <o:region>Mazowieckie</o:region>
            </o:chmiel>
            <o:browar typek="jasne">
                <o:name>Kasztelan</o:name>
                <o:rozlewnia>Sierpc</o:rozlewnia>
                <o:rok_założenia>1972</o:rok_założenia>

                <o:alkohol>5,7%</o:alkohol>
            </o:browar>
            <o:opis>Naturalne składniki, tradycyjna receptura, brak pasteryzacji to sekrety wyjątkowego smaku piwa Kasztelan Niepasteryzowane.</o:opis>
        </o:piwo>

        <o:piwo id="p14" from="zagraniczne">
            <o:nazwa>Budweiser Budvar Original</o:nazwa>
            <o:chmiel>
                <o:kraj idref="p101">Czechy</o:kraj>
                <o:region>Kotlina Czeskobudziejowicka</o:region>
            </o:chmiel>
            <o:browar typek="ciemne">
                <o:name>Budějovický Budvar</o:name>
                <o:rozlewnia>Czeskie Budziejowice</o:rozlewnia>
                <o:rok_założenia>1265</o:rok_założenia>

                <o:alkohol>5,0%</o:alkohol>
            </o:browar>
            <o:opis>Budweiser to piwo wręcz legendarne, jedno z najbardziej znanych czeskich piw. Powstaje tylko i wyłącznie w Czeskich Budziejowicach, dzięki czemu ma każdym kontynencie smakuje dokładnie tak samo. 
            Tradycja warzenia piwa Budweiser według niezmiennej od lat, oryginalnej receptury liczy 700 lat. Rewelacyjny smak, łagodny, a jednocześnie z wyraźnym posmakiem lekkiej goryczki. Głęboki kolor i idealne nasycenie to jego dodatkowe atuty.</o:opis>
        </o:piwo>

        <o:piwo id="p15" from="zagraniczne">
            <o:nazwa>Carlsberg</o:nazwa>
            <o:chmiel>
                <o:kraj idref="p103">Dania</o:kraj>
                <o:region>Hillerod</o:region>
            </o:chmiel>
            <o:browar typek="jasne">
                <o:name>Carlsberg</o:name>
                <o:rozlewnia>Kopenhaga</o:rozlewnia>
                <o:rok_założenia>1847</o:rok_założenia>

                <o:alkohol>5,0%</o:alkohol>
            </o:browar>
            <o:opis>"Prawdopodobnie najlepsze piwo na świecie".
            Charakterystyczne zielone butelki "Vichy" z tłoczonym znakiem firmowym Carlsberga i znak firmy podkreślony od dołu wstęgą każdemu piwoszowi kojarzy się ze znakomitym trunkiem.</o:opis>
        </o:piwo>

        <o:piwo id="p16" from="zagraniczne">
            <o:nazwa>Desperados</o:nazwa>
            <o:chmiel>
                <o:kraj idref="p104">Francja</o:kraj>
                <o:region>Grand Est</o:region>
            </o:chmiel>
            <o:browar typek="jasne">
                <o:name>Fischer</o:name>
                <o:rozlewnia>Schiltigheim</o:rozlewnia>
                <o:rok_założenia>1995</o:rok_założenia>

                <o:alkohol>6,0%</o:alkohol>
            </o:browar>
            <o:opis>Desperados to najszybciej rosnąca marka Premium na polskim rynku. Unikalna formuła piwa z aromatem tequili znalazła w bardzo krótkim czasie liczne grono wielbicieli. 
            Desperados towarzyszy młodym konsumentom w trakcie zabawy zarówno w domu jak i klubach, dyskotekach. Polska to jedyny obok Francji kraj, w którym Desperados jest produkowany. Unikalna przezroczysta butelka i styl komunikacji to znaki szczególne tej marki.</o:opis>
        </o:piwo>

        <o:piwo id="p17" from="polskie">
            <o:nazwa>Książęce Czerwony Lager</o:nazwa>
            <o:chmiel>
                <o:kraj idref="p100">Polska</o:kraj>
                <o:region>Śląsk</o:region>
            </o:chmiel>
            <o:browar typek="pełne">
                <o:name>Tyskie Browary Książęce</o:name>
                <o:rozlewnia>Tychy</o:rozlewnia>
                <o:rok_założenia>1613</o:rok_założenia>

                <o:alkohol>4,9%</o:alkohol>
            </o:browar>
            <o:opis>Czerwony Lager o idealnie zbalansowanym smaku, swój wyjątkowy miedzianym kolor i kremową pianę zawdzięcza kompozycji słodów pilzneńskich i karmelowych. Przyjemny, naturalny zapach, wytrawna chmielowa goryczka oraz ciepłe karmelowe nuty podkreślają szlachetny charakter piwa.</o:opis>
        </o:piwo>

        <o:piwo id="p18" from="polskie">
            <o:nazwa>Warka Radler</o:nazwa>
            <o:chmiel>
                <o:kraj idref="p100">Polska</o:kraj>
                <o:region>Mazowieckie</o:region>
            </o:chmiel>
            <o:browar typek="jasne">
                <o:name>Warka</o:name>
                <o:rozlewnia>Warka</o:rozlewnia>
                <o:rok_założenia>1968</o:rok_założenia>

                <o:alkohol>2,0%</o:alkohol>
            </o:browar>
            <o:opis>Radler to jeden z najpopularniejszych w Europie mixów piwa z lemoniadą. Receptura oparta jest na połączeniu 40% jasnego piwa Warka z 60% lemoniady sporządzonej na bazie koncentratu soków cytrynowego i pomarańczowego. 
            Naturalnie mętny, lekki i pozbawiony nutki goryczy. Mętna konsystencja jest gwarantem obecności naturalnych składników. W smaku łączy walory jasnego piwa Warka oraz nutę cytrynowo-pomarańczowej lemoniady.</o:opis>
        </o:piwo>

        <o:piwo id="p19" from="polskie">
            <o:nazwa>Łebskie Original</o:nazwa>
            <o:chmiel>
                <o:kraj idref="p100">Polska</o:kraj>
                <o:region>Kaszuby</o:region>
            </o:chmiel>
            <o:browar typek="pełne">
                <o:name>Łebski Browar</o:name>
                <o:rozlewnia>Łeba</o:rozlewnia>
                <o:rok_założenia>1977</o:rok_założenia>

                <o:alkohol>5,6%</o:alkohol>
            </o:browar>
            <o:opis>o:piwo lekko pasteryzowane tzn. przez jedną minutę w 70°C, zachowuje wartościowe witaminy i minerały, a także jest źródłem tak korzystnie na nas działających przeciwutleniaczy. Doskonale gasi pragnienie. 
            Tradycyjnie warzone, z dodatkiem chmielu, coraz rzadziej występującego w tym szlachetnym trunku, dzięki czemu zawdzięcza ono swój wyśmienity smak.</o:opis>
        </o:piwo>

        <o:piwo id="p20" from="zagraniczne">
            <o:nazwa>Beck’s</o:nazwa>
            <o:chmiel>
                <o:kraj idref="p105">Niemcy</o:kraj>
                <o:region>Brema</o:region>
            </o:chmiel>
            <o:browar typek="ciemne">
                <o:name>Beck’s Brewery</o:name>
                <o:rozlewnia>Bremen</o:rozlewnia>
                <o:rok_założenia>1873</o:rok_założenia>

                <o:alkohol>5,0%</o:alkohol>
            </o:browar>
            <o:opis>Beck’s jest wspaniałym przedstawicielem grupy pilznerów. W swojej klasie należy z pewnością do liderów. Beck’s to piwo znane i cieszące się uznaniem niemal na całym świecie. Jest warzone od lat zgodnie z „niemieckim prawem czystości składu piwa”.</o:opis>
            </o:piwo>

            <o:lista_producentów>
                <o:producent id="p100" short_name="PL">
                    <o:nazwa_2>Polska</o:nazwa_2>
                </o:producent>   
                <o:producent id="p101" short_name="CZ">
                    <o:nazwa_2>Czechy</o:nazwa_2>
                </o:producent>   
                <o:producent id="p102" short_name="NL">
                    <o:nazwa_2>Holandia</o:nazwa_2>
                </o:producent>   
                <o:producent id="p103" short_name="DK">
                    <o:nazwa_2>Dania</o:nazwa_2>
                </o:producent>   
                <o:producent id="p104" short_name="FR">
                    <o:nazwa_2>Francja</o:nazwa_2>
                </o:producent>   
                <o:producent id="p105" short_name="GER">
                    <o:nazwa_2>Niemcy</o:nazwa_2>    
                </o:producent>   
            </o:lista_producentów>     

    </p:piwa_i_alkohole>
</p:projekt>
```

alko.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:cmn="http://piwowarzy.pl/tytul"
           targetNamespace="http://piwowarzy.pl/alko"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:import schemaLocation="tytuł.xsd"
               namespace="http://piwowarzy.pl/tytul" />

    <xs:complexType name="alko" >   
        <xs:sequence>                                   
            <xs:element name="piwo" maxOccurs="unbounded" >             
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="nazwa" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="chmiel" >                             
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>                                            
                                    <xs:element name="kraj">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:simpleContent>
                                                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                                    <xs:attribute name="idref">    
                                                        <xs:simpleType>                                             
                                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:ID" >
                                                                <xs:pattern value="[p][1][0][0-5]" />                               
                                                            </xs:restriction>
                                                        </xs:simpleType>    
                                                    </xs:attribute>                                                                                     

                                                </xs:extension>                                             
                                            </xs:simpleContent>
                                        </xs:complexType>   
                                    </xs:element>
                                    <xs:element name="region" type="xs:string" />   
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>                               
                    </xs:sequence>

                    <xs:attribute name="id" >
                        <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:ID" >
                                <xs:pattern value="[p][0-2][0-9]" />                             
                            </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>    
                    </xs:attribute>
                    <xs:attribute name="from" >
                        <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN" >
                                <xs:enumeration value="polskie" />
                                <xs:enumeration value="zagraniczne" />                              
                            </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>    
                    </xs:attribute> 
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>   

            <xs:element name="browar" maxOccurs="unbounded" >                     
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="rozlewnia" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="rok_założenia" >  
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer" >
                                    <xs:minInclusive value="1" />
                                    <xs:maxInclusive value="2018" />
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>   
                        <xs:element name="alkohol">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal" >
                                    <xs:fractionDigits value="1" />
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>   
                    </xs:sequence>

                    <xs:attribute name="typek">
                        <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string" >
                                <xs:enumeration value="jasne" />
                                <xs:enumeration value="ciemne" />
                                <xs:enumeration value="pełne" />                            
                            </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:attribute>
                </xs:complexType>   
            </xs:element>

                <xs:element name="opis" >
                    <xs:complexType>                                
                        <xs:attribute name="opis" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:complexType>    
                </xs:element>

                <xs:element name="lista_producentów" >
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="producent" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>                               
                                        <xs:element name="nazwa_2" type="xs:string" />
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:attribute name="id" >
                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:ID" >
                                                <xs:pattern value="[p][1][0][0-5]" />                             
                                            </xs:restriction>
                                        </xs:simpleType>    
                                    </xs:attribute>
                                    <xs:attribute name="short_name" use="required"/>  
                                </xs:complexType> 
                            </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType> 
            </xs:element>

    </xs:sequence>                              
    </xs:complexType>   
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your schema only allows `piwo` to have two children, `nazwa` and `chmiel`, so it's not surprising that it doesn't allow the third child `browar` which appears in your instance, is it?

Similarly, your definition of the type for "id" explicitly allows only two digits, so you should expect the value "p100" to be rejected.

Generally, you seem to be getting the validation errors that I would expect you to get, and it's not clear from your post why you find them surprising.